# Understanding the output files in a Datastore export

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

We need to export our Datastore DB from Google Cloud to our local development evironment. I managed to export it and save it in a folder on the Storage. However, there are over a hundred files that are named: "output-{number}". Is not clear for me if we must use all of them in order to import the DB on local, or I just need one of this outputs.

The export created has the following structure:

```
default_namespace/
    all_kinds/
        default_namespace_all_kinds.export_metadata
        output-0
        output-1
        ...
        output-N
```

Is the entire "default_namespace" directory needed to successfully import the data from Prod to Local?

If you need more information please write a comment and I will provide it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datasatore exports are expected to generate many different files as specified in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#metadata_files)

However, the file you should use to perform the import is the one with the extension `.overall_export_metadata`. (Example: `file-name.overall_export_metadata`)

If what you want to do is import the Datastore Database to a local instance of the Datastore Emulator, take a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/emulator-export-import#import_entities_into_the_emulator)

Comment: Thank you, I just managed to make it work, this is what I was looking for.